# Redirect within a function (React)

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to understand why this is returning an error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`
as far as Im aware the value being passed into LessonId is correct.

Further upstream I am able to just `<Redirect to="/edit/Lesson/"+LessonId; />` but im currently trying to redirect on doubleclick hence the function.

```
<tr className="lessonTableRow" key={lesson.lessonId} onDoubleClick={() =>{ lessonTableRowLink(lesson.lessonId)}}>
```

```
const lessonTableRowLink =  (LessonId:number|undefined) => {

        let link = '/edit/Lesson/'+LessonId;

        <Redirect to= {link} />
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the return statement;
You should return it,so,react can render the page.

```
const lessonTableRowLink =  (LessonId:number|undefined) => {

        let link = '/edit/Lesson/'+LessonId;
        return <Redirect to= {link} /> // add return
    }
```

You should also check for [`NavLink`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) or [`history#push`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)

Comment: Thanks for showing the reason why the code above was not working, I would say that this is closest to my original code and gets the intended task done.

Comment: @ChristianCuneo consider to accept it if its working fine

Answer (score 0):

JSX doesn't do anything on its own, and ESLint is warning you about this. Instead, you have to use React Router's `history` API

```
history.replace(link)
```

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on this a bit more?

I did a bit of google searching and from what i understand ```history.push``` is going to insert the desired redirect link into the browser history stack?

Comment: Actually you'd want to use `history.replace`. It works almost exactly the same as `Redirect`, which actually calls `history.replace` by default. Here's the code if you're curious: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/7b76d314edb185fb90e38e7ebdb9ca0dc8a8d601/packages/react-router/modules/Redirect.js#L21

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `react-router-dom`'s `useHistory` hook for this.

You're code could look something like this:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const lessonTableRowLink = (LessonId:number|undefined) => {
    let link = '/edit/Lesson/'+LessonId;
    history.push(link);
  }

  return (
    ...
      <tr className="lessonTableRow" key={lesson.lessonId} onDoubleClick={() =>{ lessonTableRowLink(lesson.lessonId)}}>
    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: This is the closest to the solution that I ended up using but want to give a thanks to all for putting in their two cents.

Comment: No problem, could you give a +1 and mark as answered please :)